# Python2.7 code to extract only strings from list containing unicode characters, blank spaces and square brackets

Tags: python, regex, list, regex-lookarounds, unicode-string

I have a list with some unicode characters, blank spaces and square brackets :

```
alist = [u'[', u'', u'I', u'', u'want, want &amp; want', u'', u'only &amp; only', u'', u'this', u'', u'\\n', u'', u']', u'', u'']
```

How do I modify the above list using Python2.7 so that the list contains only the relevant string items 'I', 'want, want & want', 'only & only', 'this'?

```
alist = ['I', 'want, want & want', 'only & only', 'this']
```

Comment: How did you even get this list? It sounds like you did something horrible with a raw HTML file that you should have used a parser for.

Comment: Never mind. I solved this using below code :                              
  crumb_list = []
  for breadcrumb in breadcrumbs:
        breadcrumb = breadcrumb.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore')             breadcrumb = breadcrumb.replace('&amp;', '&')      
        if breadcrumb not in ('' , '['  , ']' , '\n'):
            crumb_list.append(breadcrumb) 
    print "Crumb LIST :",crumb_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I solved this using below code :
 crumb_list = []
 for breadcrumb in breadcrumbs:
        breadcrumb = breadcrumb.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        breadcrumb = breadcrumb.replace('&', '&')
        if breadcrumb not in ('' , '['  , ']' , '\n'):
            crumb_list.append(breadcrumb) 
  print "Crumb LIST :",crumb_list